# Semantic UI Segments

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

[image: How to code this segment in Semantic UI?]

How to code this segment in Semantic UI? I tried using grids too, but it unfortunately didn't work out.

```
<div class="ui horizontal segments">

            <div class="ui segment">
                <div class="two column row">
                    <div class="column">

                    </div>
                    <div class="column">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui segment">

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, this will give us a point to start from. As it is, it looks like you want us to do all the work for you, and StackOverflow is NOT a code writing service.

Comment: @JonP I have added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cHkLiIRbKYrJC1ugEXx4?p=preview) fits with what you're looking for

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <!-- left part --> 
    <div class="eight wide column">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- right part -->
    <div class="eight wide column"></div>
</div>
```

Grid separated on two wide equal columns. On the right column, three rows, on the left column, your content.

Comment: Thanks. But, I want the borders to appear too. And the right part's width is slightly lesser than the left part's width.

Comment: I gave you the skeleton. I won't gave you the full code, because it's not that harder to make it.
You have to try by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think with some css and Semantic segments, you can achieve this.
Here's what I tried. Apologies for indentation!

```
<div class="ui segments" style="width: 400px;float: left;">

<div class="ui compact horizontal segments">
<div class="ui segment" style="width: 100px;padding: 0;border-radius: 0px;">
    <div class="ui segments" style="width: 200px;float: left;border: 0px;border-radius: 0px;border-right: 1px solid #eee;">
<div class="ui segment" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee !important;">
  <p>Nested Top</p>
</div>
<div class="ui segment" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee!important; ">
  <p>Nested Middle</p>
</div>
<div class="ui segment">
  <p>Nested Bottom</p>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="ui segment" style="width: 99px;background: #fff;"><p>Nested Horizontal</p> </div></div></div>
```